# How %g rounds up floating point numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

While I'm using `%g` as format specifier in `printf()`, sometimes it rounds up upto 2 places after decimal point, sometimes upto 3 places , someimes upto 4 places...how it does so?

Actually where we should use `%g` instead of `%f` or `%e` for floating point numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%g` format specifier does its rounding just like `%f` would do, but if `%f` would result in `4.234000`, then `%g` will omit the trailing zeros and print `4.234`.

`%g` should be used when it makes the most sense in your output format that some numbers are printed as `12345.6`, while a slightly bigger number would be printed as `1.235e04`.

Answer (score 5):

`%g` automatically 'flips' between using `%e` and `%f` depending on the value, in an attempt to display as much information as possible, in the same way as hand-held calculators do.
Also, with `%g` trailing zeroes and decimal point are not included.

Answer (score 4):

For the `%f` conversion, the “precision” is the number of digits **after the decimal point**, while for `%g` it is the number of **significant** digits.
The default precision is 6 in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

From the [printf manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

"The double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or E  for
              G  conversions).  The precision specifies the number of significant digits.  If the precision is missing, 6 digits  are  given;
              if  the  precision is zero, it is treated as 1.  Style e is used
              if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4  or  greater
              than or equal to the precision.  Trailing zeros are removed from
              the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears  only
              if it is followed by at least one digit."

I don't mean to "RTFM", but you'll probably find what you're looking for in the manual sections on controlling precision and length.