# String formatting with maximum number of digits

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I'm trying to format floating point numbers with a *maximum* number of digits, but I don't want unnecessary **trailing zeroes**. I thought if I use `g` instead of `f` it would work (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839408/how-g-rounds-up-floating-point-numbers))

```
def testF(d: Double) = f"$d%1.2f"
def testG(d: Double) = f"$d%1.2g"
```

Now this behaves rather strangely:

```
testF(3.1415)  // --> 3.14 ok
testF(3.1)     // --> 3.10 hmmm, don't want that zero

testG(3.1415)  // --> 3.1 what the ?
```

Ok, so perhaps I need to increase the digits by one for `g`:

```
def testG(d: Double) = f"$d%1.3g"

testG(3.1415)  // --> 3.14 ok
testG(3.1)     // --> 3.10 grmpf
```

So two questions—one, why the heck is `g` dropping one digit and doesn't seem to care about trailing zeroes? Two, how can I have

```
testX(3.1415)  // --> 3.14
testX(3.1)     // --> 3.1
```

?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf?lq=1) but for Scala/Java

Comment: `f"$d%1.2f".reverse.dropWhile{ _ == '0' }.dropWhile{ _ == '.' }.reverse`. I don't think you can do it with formatting only.

Comment: @0__ Did you try my method? You first commented that it didn't work but now the comment is gone. For me it works with `testX(3.1)` and without problems.

Comment: This is interview question territory.  I guess the Google interview question would be: Estimate how much time has been spent on printf formats since the unix epoch, expressed in man-eons (excuse the sexist term). Why is there no +1? We can pad zero but not ignore trailing? Are they saving us from doing evil wrt precision?

Comment: @maba - yes, I had a wrong reference in my REPL history which led me to believe it didn't work, but I figured it out and indeed it works. If there are no other suggestions more integrated with string interp, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I thought you wanted integration with f"s". Since you mentioned it, I like the idea of not dropping out of my usual syntax. (It was helpful to be reminded about `java.text`, for my next Scala Swing app.)

Comment: That's the first time I had use for a regex with an embedded ellipsis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the java [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) but it may not please the eye:

```
def testX(d: Double) = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.##").format(d)
```

Also to answer your first question *why the heck is `g` dropping one digit and doesn't seem to care about trailing zeroes*

> For the floating-point conversions 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the **number of digits after the decimal separator**. If the conversion is 'g' or 'G', then the precision is the **total number of digits** in the resulting magnitude after rounding.

[Formatter details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail)

Answer (score 3):

As with the C world's printf, Java's (and Scala's) `Formatter` includes both minimum and maximum field widths (for the `%s` format specifier):

```
// Minimum field width -- right-aligned
scala> "%23s".format(23)
res0: String = "                     23"

// Minimum field width -- left-aligned
scala> "%-23s".format(23)
res1: String = "23                     "

// Maximum field width with right truncation
scala> "%.3s".format(12345)
res2: String = 123

// Minimum and maximum width -- right aligned
scala> "%3.3s".format(1)
res3: String = "  1"

// Minimum and maximum width -- left aligned
scala> "%-3.3s".format(1)
res4: String = "1  "
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this version?

The use of `Formattable` requires the `%s` format, but you're given the formatting args to interpret as you like.

A `Formattable` can pop up in the middle of an `f`-interpolation, since the normal `format` just uses either `toString` or your custom `formatTo`.

```
package object succinctly {
  import java.util.{ Formattable, FormattableFlags, Formatter }
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit class Succinctly(val __thing: Double) extends AnyVal {
    @inline def succinctly(s: String): String = s format fmtable(__thing)
    @inline def succinctly: Formattable = fmtable(__thing)
  }
  private[this] val trailing = "(.*\\...*?)(0*)".r
  private[this] def fmtable(a: Double) = new Formattable {
    override def formatTo(formatter: Formatter, flags: Int, width: Int, precision: Int) = formatter.out append (
      if (precision <= 0) a.toInt.toString
      else s"%${width}.${precision}f" format a.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Double] match { case trailing(num, _) => num }
    )
  }
}

package succinctly {
  import scala.language.postfixOps
  import scala.math._
  object Test extends App {
    Console println (Pi succinctly "%1.2s")
    Console println (3.1 succinctly "%1.2s")
    Console println (3.0 succinctly "%1.2s")
    Console println f"${3.1 succinctly}%1.2s"
  }
}
```

It's also conceivable to write a custom interpolator that promotes doubles to trailless and changes `%f` to `%s`, though at some cost, since the `f`-interpolator is a macro.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I think it's a bit too much for an occasional drop in :) Good to know about `Formattable`, though.